# XPath: accessing something that is not an attribute

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I try to access the time (07.12.2012 00:36 Uhr) from the following snippet using lxml and a xpath-command. Unfortunately the wished information is not an attribute. Which xpath can I use to access it?

My snippet:

```
{'class': 'artikeldiskussion-titel'}
<div class="artikeldiskussion-titel"><span id="posting-649631-titel"><b>So</b></span>

    <span id="an_id" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; z-index: 999;"    class="hint_grau">

    </span> <span class="anz-postings-user" title="759 Kommentare">(759)</span> &#183;           07.12.2012 00:36 Uhr
</div>
```

Comment: To answer this question one needs to know not only what the HTML looks like, but what it *might* look like - how much variation is possible? For example, will the required text always be preceded by a span with string value "(759)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is messy html.

Without seeing more samples, I would suggest one of two approaches:

1. Grab the last text node in the div: `/descendant::div[@class="artikeldiskussion-titel"]/child::text()[position()=last()]`
2. Grab the text node after some sentinel node: `/descendant::span[@class="anz-postings-user"]/following-sibling::text()[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `text()` xpath function:

```
txt = tree.xpath('//path/to/span/text()')
```